# 3D Enemy wave system Issues C# (collision & spawning)

Tags: c#

I am in the process of re-making a basic call of duty zombies style game, I'm really new to unity and programming in general (about 2 weeks in) so please go easy with explaining.

the first issue - I currently have a wave system spawning in multiple capsules that follow the player however they seem to not collide with the environment or each other despite the environment having a box collider and capsules having capsule colliders.

The second issue - the wave system came from a Brackys video but the "waiting" function does not seem to work and i can not work out why. The waiting function is supposed to wait until all alive enemy's have been killed then it will spawn the next wave but it seems to skip the waiting function and continuously spawn in capsules.

My question is if anyone has any input on how to resolve these issues i would hugely appreciate it.

**For the first issue with collisions**

I have tried altering the collider size & shape & adding multiple colliders, this caused numerous issues such as the capsules were stacking on top of each other and as this is a 3D first person shooter the "hit box" for the capsules were the same size as the enlarged colliders.

**For the second issue with spawning**

the wave spawn code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaveSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum SpawnState { SPAWNING, WAITING, COUNTING };

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public string name;
        public Transform enemy;
        public int count;
        public float rate;
    }

    public Wave[] waves;
    private int nextWave = 0;
    public int NextWave
    {
        get { return nextWave + 1; }
    }

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;

    public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
    private float waveCountdown;
    public float WaveCountdown
    {
        get { return waveCountdown; }
    }

    private float searchCountdown = 1f;

    private SpawnState state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
    public SpawnState State
    {
        get { return state; }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (spawnPoints.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No spawn points referenced.");
        }

        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (state == SpawnState.WAITING)
        {
            if (EnemyIsAlive())
            {
                WaveCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (waveCountdown <= 0)
        {
            if (state != SpawnState.SPAWNING)
            {
                StartCoroutine( SpawnWave ( waves[nextWave] ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waveCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void WaveCompleted()
    {
        Debug.Log("Wave Completed!");

        state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;

        if (nextWave + 1 > waves.Length - 1)
        {
            nextWave = 0;
            Debug.Log("ALL WAVES COMPLETE! Looping...");
        }
        else
        {
            nextWave++;
        }
    }

    bool EnemyIsAlive()
    {
        searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
        {
            searchCountdown = 1f;
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
        state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;

        for (int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
        }

        state = SpawnState.WAITING;

        yield break;
    }

    void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);

        Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
        Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
    }

}
```

I think the issues lies in the following:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (state == SpawnState.WAITING)
        {
            if (EnemyIsAlive())
            {
                WaveCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

i have tried swapping the wave competed and return functions but that didnt work, i feel like saying if (EnemyIsAlive) followed by WaveCompleted(); is causing the issue but i can not work out a fix.

Comment: Tag this as Unity3d as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of potential issues that could cause problems with colliders but i'll give it a shot:

Issue #1:

1. The environment will need some sort of collider to register collisions, both objects in question will need a collider - Try putting a box collider around an object and see if they continue to go through it.
2. Check to see if you have a Kinematic rigidbody.  If you are using a rigidbody for movement "is kinematic" will expect some coding to handle the physics of the collision.  If you are looking for a simple solution I would recommend looking at the "Character Controller" class.
3. Make sure if you are using a Mesh collider that the object has a mesh.

Issue #2:

At a quick glance this stood out to me

```
if (state != SpawnState.SPAWNING)
{
    StartCoroutine( SpawnWave ( waves[nextWave] ) );
}
```

Looking at this from a code readability standpoint I'm interpreting it as follows:

`If the state is NOT Spawning -> Spawn`

`also, remove the RETURN statement in Update (it is void meaning it does not return a value)  - the update thread runs constantly, You should use conditions to determine what occurs in the scene`

Hope this helped!